# Free wifi in Reykjavik

Tags: internet, wifi, iceland

Do coffee shops or similar in Reykjavik have free wifi? I'll be traveling there with friends and want to be able to report in that we're alive after the hike. I don't really want to use GSM internet for this as I have a CDMA only phone and don't want to have to purchase a different phone just for this purpose.

Comment: Would internet-cafés be an acceptable solution?

Answer (score 8):

There are many cafés and other access points in downtown Reykjavik that offer free wifi ([list](http://www.hotspot-locations.co.uk/modules.php?op=hotspot_query&name=HotSpots&hsl_countryhs=IS&hs_state=&hs_city=&hs_operator=&hsl_type=&hs_access_box=&hs_roaming=&externalquery=&backFrom=0&moreFrom=30&more=%3E%3E)
[list](http://freewifiwiki.net/index.php?title=Iceland),
[map](http://www.wificafespots.com/wifi/city/IS--Reykjavik)), as well as a number of [Vodafone hotspots](http://www.vodafone.is/en/getonline/hotspots/map) which as far as I can tell are free to everyone, not just Vodafone customers. Coverage is more sporadic elsewhere in Iceland.